# Is there a way to force the "most vexing parse" to be an error, even on a class by class basis?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

Is it possible (with any modification of class A) to have the following work?  i.e., make the most vexing parse an error?

```
class A {
};

int main() {
    A a(); // can this be forced to be an error??
    A b;   // this should work
}
```

Comment: Unlikely. Remember that this is parsed as a function declaration, so you would need a modification to the type `A` that prevents `A` from being a return type of a function (even if no such function is ever even defined) while still being instantiable. If this is a real problem for you, I'd try to find a static analysis tool that will catch possible instances of this.

Comment: Why? It's not an error. It's your expectations that are erred.

Comment: This is **not** the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki). It is simply a function declaration.

Comment: If `A a()` was an error, how would you declare a function that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `A`?

Comment: I could envision a checker in clang to disable local function declarations and complains there. Really, how many people do use local function declarations in real code?

Comment: Oops, the link that I intended was [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No modification of the class `A` will have any effect on how a declaration `A a();` is parsed. The parser determines that this is a function declaration before it even bothers to look at the definition of `A`. In fact the definition of `A` doesn't even need to be visible to parse this statement; A forward declaration is sufficient.

However compilers generally have a warning for this and you can probably turn that into an error. For example with clang you can use the flag <kbd>-Werror=vexing-parse</kbd>.

```
struct A;

A a(); // no error

int main() {
    A a(); // error
}
```

<kbd>clang++ -std=c++11 -Weverything -Werror=vexing-parse main.cpp</kbd>

```
main.cpp:6:8: error: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Werror,-Wvexing-parse]
    A a();
       ^~
main.cpp:6:8: note: replace parentheses with an initializer to declare a variable
    A a();
       ^~
       {}
1 error generated.
```

---

Although technically speaking `A a();` isn't the syntax known as the most vexing parse. That would be:

```
A a(B());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in the current language specification which could make this code an error. Normally, you just get a funny error message when you try to use the "object". However, some compilers do warn about the situation (e.g. clang):

```
clang++ -W -Wall  -Werror -c -o vexing.o vexing.cpp
vexing.cpp:5:8: error: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Werror,-Wvexing-parse]
   A a(); // can this be forced to be an error??
      ^~
```