# Force disambiguation of most vexing parse to be function declaration

Tags: c++, clang, most-vexing-parse

All of the discussions I've seen on the "most vexing parse" talk about how to force the compiler to treat the case as a variable declaration with initializer (instead of the actual interpretation as a function declaration). See, for example, [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009306/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-most-vexing-parse-to-be-an-error-even-on-a-class) and [this article from Ask-Coder](http://www.acnenomor.com/194873p1/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).

My team has a rule: force as many warnings as possible to be errors. The goal is to keep cruft from creeping into the code; successful compiles should be silent, and disabling warnings is a recipe for disaster. That's all very well and good, except I'm being bitten by the Most Vexing Parse on a declaration that actually parses the way I want it to parse.

Specifically:

```
int some_function();
```

As shown in the Ask-Coder article, this code fragment really does trip the Most Vexing Parse warning in clang, which we then convert to an error, which kicks me in the teeth.

Is there anything I can do in the syntax here to make this (a) a legal C declaration (not just C++) and (b) not trip the Most Vexing Parse warning? Or do I have to do the  #pragma dance and silence the warning right around this line of code?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be as simple as

```
int some_function(void);
```